# Video mimetypes supported in uploading using Youtube v3 API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am posting youtube videos using Youtube v3 API.
I convert my .mp4 video files to a readable stream and upload it using the /insert endpoint.
I was wondering what other them .mp4 video types can I upload to youtube by converting them to a readable stream.

I have posted several .mp4 videos but want to what else mimetypes does it support.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says [videos.insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert)

> Accepted Media MIME types: video/*, application/octet-stream

So I would assume all of these are supported.

[image]